# get error when i wana to show 3 numbers of popular posts in submenu (max mega menu)

Tags: wordpress

I wana to show 3 numbers of popular posts (wordpress) in sub menu (max mega menu plugin) but when i try to do it , i get a error that contain this message
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on null

```
<?php $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT comment_count,ID,post_title FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0 , 5");
    foreach ($result as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $postid = $post->ID;
        $title = $post->post_title;
        $commentcount = $post->comment_count;
        if ($commentcount != 0) { ?>
            <li class="maxmenu-topnews">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
            </li>
        <?php } }
 ?>
```

Comment: You need to bring `$wpdb` into your function's local scope. You can use `global $wpdb` for that, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As George has already added into the comments that you need to add global keyword for $wpdb.

Your final code will be:

```
    global $wpdb;
 $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT comment_count,ID,post_title FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0 , 5");
    foreach ($result as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        $postid = $post->ID;
        $title = $post->post_title;
        $commentcount = $post->comment_count;
        if ($commentcount != 0) { ?>
            <li class="maxmenu-topnews">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
            </li>
        <?php } }
        ?>
```